# Eclipse thinks my JRE is 1.6, when I've migrated to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-6

I am having a problem with `Eclipse Luna` after an update. Despite showing in the tree for the project that it is using `JRE system library 1.7` the error checking is reporting bugs with a switch using a string that it has a source level below `1.7`.

The specific error:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
```

I have tried going into `Properties > Build Path` and adding and removing the library but this has not fixed the problem.

I moved from the Eclipse packaged with `Debain Wheezy` which uses the `1.6 JDK` and the much older `Eclipse 3.8`. I am now using `CentOS 7` with the `1.7 JDK`. The migration has not been as smooth as I hoped. Since there has some big version jumps, I need help getting this new `4.4` version working properly.

Comment: The used system library is not the same as the used compiler, the compiler has its own section in the eclipse/project settings. When you are using maven, you also have to set the target version to 1.7 in the pom.xml!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> Java Compiler -> set the compiler level to 1.7

Same for Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> 1.7

If you can't find that option (by which I mean Compiler `1.7`), you must specify the Installed JRE to be JDK 7 too.